# How to use "print" colored output in python 3 with Sublime 3

Tags: python

I hope that you guys can help me to solve this problem.
I am using Sublime text 3. everything is fine, but I would like to print colored output such as print ("Hello world", "red")  and the output with thr red "Hello world". However I only can do it in Spyder or Visual Studio Code, in Sublime the program always gives an output: [31mhello[0m [32mworld[0m
Even I tried to use colorama or termcolor. Maybe my configuration for Sublime has a problem. Please help me if you can

P/S: I am an unregistered user. Do they limited to unregistered users?

Thank you so much for reading.

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
print(Back.GREEN + 'and with a green background')
print(Style.DIM + 'and in dim text')
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print('back to normal now')
```

or with termcolor

```
from termcolor import colored
print(colored('hello', 'red'), colored('world', 'green'))
```

I would like to have the same result in Sublime Text 3.

Comment: well one thing is sure that it's nothing to do with Sublime. Because I have similar output while on VS code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not running the python code in the terminal. You can see the difference between the output.

- **In terminal**
  [image: output in terminal window]
- **Simple Output**
  [image]

> As you can see the problem is not with any code editor, but the fact is where you are printing it. If you run the above code using Sublime terminal window you will get the colored output.

Psst...It's not publicity but my love with VS code, I recommend to use VS code if that popup screen (Trial expired:-() annoy you.

Comment: Thank you so  much for your answer, but in Sublime I do not see Terminal anywhere. Can you give me some keyword to search them in google?

Comment: @PiPi Sorry this is late, but I'm pretty sure it is because you have to `import os`, and then do `os.system("cls")`, you can check out my library if you want: https://github.com/CodeForeverAndEver/ColorIt